# middleware function in go kit

Tags: go, microservices

I have trouble understanding go-kit middleware so I have a logging middleware set up for my retail_total api endpoint.

```
func MakeTotalRetailPriceHttpHandler(logger log.Logger, svc PricingService) *httptransport.Server {
    var retailEndpoint endpoint.Endpoint
    retailEndpoint = MakeTotalRetailPriceEndpoint(svc)
    retailEndpoint = LogTotalRetailPriceEndpoint(log.With(logger, "service", "PricingService"))(retailEndpoint)

    return httptransport.NewServer(
        retailEndpoint,
        decodeTotalRetailPriceRequest,
        encodeResponse,
    )
}
```

Here's the logTotalRetailEndpoint middlware

```
func LogTotalRetailPriceEndpoint(logger log.Logger) endpoint.Middleware {
    return func(next endpoint.Endpoint) endpoint.Endpoint {
        return func(ctx context.Context, request interface{}) (interface{}, error) {
            logger.Log("endpoint", "TotalRetailPriceEndpoint", "msg", "Calling endpoint")
            defer logger.Log("endpoint", "TotalRetailPriceEndpoint", "msg", "Called endpoint")

            // diagnostic functionality

            return next(ctx, request)
        }
    }
}
```

Now my doubt is that logging middleware contains function which take parameters like context and request and these parameters are used by next. How do they get passed to the middlware??